# Abi-decoder returns undefined

Tags: javascript, uniswap, abi

Here is my code:

```
 const abiDecoder = require('abi-decoder');
    
    UNISWAP_ROUTER_ABI = Abi from UniswapV3 router 2. I took it here : [https://etherscan.io/address/0x68b3465833fb72a70ecdf485e0e4c7bd8665fc45#code][1]
    
    
      [1]: https://etherscan.io/address/0x68b3465833fb72a70ecdf485e0e4c7bd8665fc45#code
    
    abiDecoder.addABI(UNISWAP_ROUTER_ABI);
    
    function parseTx(input) {
            if (input == '0x')
                return ['0x', []]
                
            let decodedData = abiDecoder.decodeMethod(input);
            console.log(decodedData)
            let method = decodedData['name'];
            let params = decodedData['params'];
        
            return [method, params]
        }

async function getTrans(){
    TX = await web3.eth.getTransaction("0x4dff5ac507c85dcd4ed3fc4bc0d09c8d1fefedfabd9d02501800368dca1c29a1");
    return TX}

    async function getTX(){
      TX = await getTrans()
      let data = parseTx(TX['input']);
      let method = data[0];
      let params = data[1];
      
  }
  getTX()
```

`console.log(decodedData)` returns undefined. I tried to decode it manually in some online services. The same problem. It's my first attempt to decode smth from smart contract. I spent several hours trying to find out what's the problem and tried abis from another Uniswap V3 router. But it doesn't help. May be I'm using the wrong abi? That's why it doesn't work with online services?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I simply made it all in one function and it worked.

```
async function getTX(){
    TX = await web3.eth.getTransaction("0x4dff5ac507c85dcd4ed3fc4bc0d09c8d1fefedfabd9d02501800368dca1c29a1");
    
    let decodedData = abiDecoder.decodeMethod(TX['input']);
    console.log(decodedData)
   
  
  }
```